# If statement within a function just doesn't work

Tags: jquery

The PHP file returns a `1` if there is no useful data. If there is useful data then I would like to add it after the `<p>`. It does this, but it appends the `1` as well. Does anybody see where I am going wrong?

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'gettweetcode.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (text) {
            if (text != 1) {
                $("p").after(text);
                $("table").fadeIn(1500);
            };
        }
    });
}, 1000); // JavaScript Document
```

Comment: Most likely your PHP output is more than a single character. `text.length` will confirm.

Comment: It does work. It's just not working as expected. View the *actual* response and/or attach a debugger and inspect the *actual* value. Also, even though JavaScript will coerce types in that case, please use "1" to represent a string.

Comment: @Jon, this way $.trim function should help, but it does not.

Comment: Probably your successful data contains 1 at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

Check for string if that is what is returned, and try trimming off whitespace, as that is sometmes an issue:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'gettweetcode.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (text) {
            if ( $.trim(text) != "1") {
                $("p").after(text);
                $("table").fadeIn(1500);
            };
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I have it working. I had more than 1 coming out of the php file. if ( $.trim(text) != "1") {
                $("p").after(text);
                $("table").fadeIn(1500);
            };

Comment: @IainCheyne - does that mean $.trim solved the issue then (this is not an uncommon issue btw).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 if ($.trim(text) !== '1') ...
```

Comment: No this doesn't do it. the output of the file is definitely just 1.

Comment: Could you tell me exact string length? Probably encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this conditional `if(parseInt(text,10) !== 1)`

If it IS a 1, and ONLY a 1 it should be ok.  Catch is if it returns "1dfw" that WOULD parse to 1 as well - SO you might need to trim and substring it if that case could occur.